# Need to distinguish between Portal (the game) and Minecraft portals.

Tags: support, ambiguous-tags

Currenlty the [portal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portal) tag is applied to both games about Portal the game and Minecraft portals.

One (or both) need changing to disambiguate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was only one instance of the Minecraft version, which I have consequently removed.

[portal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portal) applies strongest to the game. It is the full title of the game, and it will soon match with an upcoming [portal-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portal-2).

As well, to describe plain portals is... not the best of tasks. It's about as useful as [door](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/door), which I'm aware exists but I'm sure many don't think it's all that necessary. It lacks the amount of universal, game-level applicability that I think is required to be [a useful semi-dependent tag](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1650/avoid-tags-that-mean-different-things-in-different-games/1657#1657).

Comment: I can now create the tag wikis ;)

Comment: You could also do "minecraft-portals". Then again, it's true that 'door' and 'portal' aren't good to just .. describe game events.

Comment: But there are a lot of issues people have with portals in minecraft, and  there are some people who are very good at fixing them.  It would be useful to connect those two groups with a tag.