# Tagging the Skyrim questions

Tags: discussion, tags

We now got nearly 500 Skyrim questions in only a week, with this high number of questions it would be really useful to have some meaningful tagging on the questions.

We haven't been very successful so far with establishing useful secondary tags on games, so before starting to retag all Skyrim questions we should put some thought into it. Finding the right balance of generality and specificity of the tags is difficult. Too general tags and too specific tags don't help, and might even hurt by adding noise to the questions.

I'm going to suggest a first draft of a tagging scheme for Skyrim, but I'm open for any other ideas on how to best tag those questions.

Comment: I'd really would rather have those skyrim subtags have a `skyrim-` prefix like the `minecraft` tags do.

Comment: @badp - I'd rather we get game tags and that prefix tags go the way of `Murder` personally, but we'll need to win over Jeff first. :/

Answer (score 10):

Here's my list.

- [combat](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combat) - any question about fighting, or how to avoid being killed in a fight, etc.
- [leveling](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leveling) - questions about earning XP, increasing one's character level, or regarding game objects which change *based* on character level.
- [crafting](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crafting) - any question that deals with enchanting, smithing, alchemey (Note: the `Alchemy` tag refers to the game by that name).
- [quests](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quests) - any question involving the way to complete or resolve a quest.
- [money](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) - any question about how to make money, attain cash, or how to best make a profit.
- [story](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story) - questions about the lore or world of the game, but not necessarily anything that comes up in gameplay (depending on the question, could benefit from [elder-scrolls-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elder-scrolls-series) instead of Skyrim).
- [puzzles](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzles) - questions about puzzle aspects of non-puzzle games. I.e., half of the "how do I open this door" questions.
- [crime](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crime) - all of Skyrim's stealth gameplay is related to thievery or murder, so I think this is the more appropriate tag. Also, there's a lot of questions about murder and thieving.
- [equipment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment) - questions about which equipment options are "best", including the handful of "Heavy vs. Light" and effects of armor on X questions. Weapons in Skyrim are generic enough to use this tag instead of the more specific [weapons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons).
- [character-build](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-build) - all questions dealing with perks, effects of perks, and how perks work.

Comment: Well, I was wondering if [tag:gathering] would be appropriate for games that have special professions for getting trade skill ingredients.

Comment: Regarding [tag:character-build], I'm still unsure how we're to handle those questions. We had more discussion about it [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2257/how-can-we-sculpt-character-strategy-build-questions), but none of my comments were addressed, so I'm still not sure how to go about these.

Comment: Would it be possible to update the tags with a rough guesstimate of how many questions would fall into each category?  I think that would be the most important part of any categorization scheme - how many Skyrim questions do we have right now that would get this tag.

Comment: @JasonBerkan The only way to do that would be to look at each question individually... and if you're doing that, why not just tag them all at the same time, anyway?

Answer (score 1):

- [melee-combat](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/melee-combat)
- [spellcasting](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spellcasting) <- [magic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic)
- [archery](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archery)
- crafting skills:

  - [alchemy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alchemy)
  - [smithing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smithing)
  - [enchanting](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enchanting)
- [leveling](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leveling) <- [skills](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skills) <- [perks](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perks)
- [dragons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragons) (maybe, prominent feature of the game, but very specific tag)
- [crime](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crime) <- [stealing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stealing) <- [pickpocketing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pickpocketing)
- [quests](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quests)
- [companions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/companions)
- [armor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/armor)
- [shops](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shops) <- [merchants](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/merchants)

Comment: I would rather suggest condensing several of these - all of the crafting elements into a [crafting] tag, and that combat-related tags would be best under a single [combat] tag. I think those avoid being too general because they are still very concrete divisions, yet aren't as specific which allows them to remain globally useful.

Comment: @Grace I'm not sure if we should really aim to make the tags globally useful. That's how we ended up with [tag:game-mechanics].

Comment: game-mechanics was very vague, though, that was the issue. It was a bit too catch-all. boss-fights is a pretty strong tag while being globally useful, for example. These sub-tags operate best when they represent something tangible and solid, yet it isn't so confusing that you absolutely require context-sensitive knowledge to know what it means with a game.

Comment: @Fabian: Tags other than the game name really shouldn't be game-specific.  The problem is, moving the crafting skills over to a different game ends up adding a whole bunch more. For example, for World of Warcraft, I'd add [tag:tailoring], [tag:leatherworking], [tag:blacksmithing], [tag:engineering], [tag:jewelcrafting], and [tag:inscription] (plus argue whether blacksmithing should be merged with smithing or not).  Or we could just keep [tag:crafting], which is generic enough to cover all of those.

Comment: Add to this the fact that [tag:crafting] is already being used by other games.

Answer (score -5):

[game-mechanics](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-mechanics) : for questions that ask "How does X works"

[location](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/location) : for question about where I can buy/see/find ...

[howto](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/howto) : for question about using the game (how do I change keys, how do I craft an item with a alchemy lab)

[quest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quest) : for question about a quest

[tips](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) : for asking hints about puzzles and so.

Comment: 4 out of 5 of these are terrible tags. They basically amount to "This is a question."